# Where to find the docs of axis parameter of torch.sum?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to read about the `sum` function of `torch` [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sum.html). I noticed that the following works:

```
> print(torch.sum(torch.randint(0,2,(2,2)),axis=1))
tensor([1, 0])
```

But in the docs above I don't see explanation for `axis`.

In the [signature](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b3bb234e16780ea3f3d749d2c8c156c9245eb797/aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml#L4089) of the function I see `*`:

```
torch.sum(input, *, dtype=None) → Tensor
```

Does it have to do something with this `*`? Where can I find the PyTorch docs that explains how to use `axis`? I came across with the same thing with other methods (with other arguments). So, although I know how to use `axis`, I would want to figure how to actually read the docs for the "hidden" arguments.

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch emulates much of the basic functionality of Numpy (with additional GPU acceleration and autograd mechanics) but the API also differs in some small ways. For example, PyTorch generally uses the `dim` keyword argument to specify which dimension a function should operate on while Numpy uses the `axis` keyword argument to specify the same thing.

While undocumented it appears that the PyTorch devs have allowed users to use the `axis` keyword argument in place of `dim` for the `sum` function. This is probably to make the library more compatible with NumPy functions.

Therefore

```py
torch.sum(x, dim=1)
```

is equivalent to

```py
torch.sum(x, axis=1)
```

and both specify that you want to sum-reduce along dimension `1`.

You can read about the NumPy version of `sum` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), which also provides additional examples of the `axis` argument.